# NPE in android service onStartCommand while using START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm using the following code in my service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mStartId = startId;
    handleStartCommandIntent(intent);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

private void handleStartCommandIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    if (mCompositeDisposable == null) {
        mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    }
    checkNotNull(intent, "intent cannot be null");
    String type = intent.getStringExtra(SERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE);
    <...>
}

@Override
public void completed() {
    stopSelf(mStartId);
}
```

`checkNotNull` is the first point where intent is looked at, however I'm not seeing my custom message in the stack trace. The check method looks as following:

```
public static <T> T checkNotNull(T reference, @Nullable Object errorMessage) {
    if(reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(String.valueOf(errorMessage));
    } else {
        return reference;
    }
}
```

However, I'm still seeing an NPE in my Crashlytics logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.myapp.app.internal.service.MessagingService@4134a7b8 with Intent { cmp=com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.internal.service.MessagingService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2608)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4847)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:535)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.myapp.app.internal.service.MessagingService.onStartCommand(MessagingService.java:1065)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2591)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4847)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:535)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

According to the docs my service should never receive a call with a null intent:

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then it will be scheduled for a restart and the last delivered Intent re-delivered to it again via onStartCommand(Intent, int, int). This Intent will remain scheduled for redelivery until the service calls stopSelf(int) with the start ID provided to onStartCommand(Intent, int, int). The service will not receive a onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) call with a null Intent because it will will only be re-started if it is not finished processing all Intents sent to it (and any such pending events will be delivered at the point of restart).

I couldn't reproduce it on my device, but I can see multiple users crashing with the same error.

Any suggestions why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: "I'm still seeing an NPE in my Crashlytics logs" -- your code does not seem to line up with your stack trace. I'm going to assume that your real code calls a method on the `Intent` directly in `onStartCommand()`, as the stack trace indicates. What is the specific call that it is crashing on? With regards to your problem... I agree with your interpretation of the docs. Are there any commonalities among the users (OS versions, device manufacturers, etc.)?

Comment: It's a weird stack track. My service doesn't have a line 1065, not sure where's Crashlytics getting that from. The first call on that intent is an explicit `checkNotNull` which throws a custom NPE message - `checkNotNull(intent, "intent cannot be null");`. However, that NPE message is not featured in the stack trace.

Comment: The only commonality of those crashes is the lack of usual device information. The all come through as `Unknown device`, i.e. `OS Version: 4.1.1, Device: Full Android on Emulator`

Comment: Sounds like somebody is tinkering with your app. If your `checkNotNull()` is not being triggered, and the line # does not match anything, and the stack trace does not indicate what in the method is causing the NPE, I would assume that somebody decompiled, modified, and recompiled your app, leaving the Crashlytics stuff in place.

Comment: Well, that might be the case, but we have 3 flavours of the same app and all 3 have crashes coming though on their respected crashlytics app accounts. I've updated the code to reflect the inner workings

Comment: "I've updated the code to reflect the inner workings" -- but that does not match the stack trace either. Forgetting the line numbers, the crash is coming from directly inside `onStartCommand()`, not from a `handleStartCommandIntent()` method called by `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Yep, and that's the weirdest part. I've double checked and triple checked that I'm on the right branch etc. I even decompiled my apk to check I'm returning the right constant from the `onStartCommand`. Actually, the decompiled class doesn't have `handleStartCommandIntent` method - everything is merged into `onStartCommand`. Maybe my problem is with the proguard minification...